# Create files of matching pattern from a single data file

Tags: shell, file, awk

I have a file of data type (file.dat) with ASCII data in it and consists two columns. Also this file is sorted according to first column. I want to write a script in either shell or awk in such way that new file should be created for similar record from that sorted file. Suppose I have file consists of (Four records) such as given below...

```
100.00 321342
100.00 434243
100.00 543231
100.50 743893
```

Hence according to my problem here two files should be created. One file consists of top three records and other file consists of last record according to data in first column.

File 1 contains

```
100.00 321342
100.00 434243
100.00 543231
```

File 2 contains

```
100.50 743893
```

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: Yes I have tried `awk '{print >> $1; close($1)}' inputfile` but it is giving column values as a name to created files, instead I want  Timestep_column_value.  e.g. for above input data files are created (by executing above awk script) as 100.00 and 100.50, but I want file names should be as **Timestep_100.00**

Comment: in that case: `awk '{print >> Timestep_$1; close($1)}' inputfile`

Comment: @Chris Maes, you should write your comment as an answer, however it needs to be `awk '{print >> "Timestep_"$1; close($1)}' inputfile`, note the _double-quotes_ around `"Timestep_"`, otherwise it's ignored and outputs to `100.00` and `100.50`, not `Timestep_100.00` and `Timestep_100.50`, based on current content and as per Sachin shinde's comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**your file**

```
100.00 321342  
100.00 434243  
100.00 543231  
100.50 743893
```

**what you need**

`perl -a -nE 'qx( echo "$F[0] $F[1]" >> "Timestep_$F[0]" )' file`

**output** is simply creates two file and name of one is **Timestep_100.00** and name of other is **Timestep_100.50** so it is separated by name of the **first** unique column. that's it.

```
$ cat Timestep_100.00   
100.00 321342  
100.00 434243  
100.00 543231
```

and other file

```
$ cat Timestep_100.50   
100.50 743893
```

Comment: @user3439894 he/she never said about that in its question

Answer (score 0):

This script should do the work:

```
#!/bin/sh

exec 0<file.txt

makeit=yes
while read stp num; do
  if [ -f "Timestep_$stp" ]; then
    echo "File Timestep_$stp exists, exiting."
    makeit=no
    break
  fi
done


if [ $makeit = yes ]; then
  exec 0<file.txt
  while read stp num; do
    echo "$stp $num" >> Timestep_$stp
  done
  echo "Processing done."
fi
```

The first loop checks that no file exists, otherwise the result would be wrong.